# eslint only allow camel case in style property in jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I got a PR with a style property that had margin-top instead of marginTop, I want to enforce that there can only be camelCase CSS properties in eslint.

```
<div style={{ 'margin-top': '8px' }} ></div> // should be marginTop
```

not typescript, react jsx.

Comment: Well, what you have there isn't valid JSX in the first place, so there's no way that is usable. Whoever made the PR didn't test their code at all.

Comment: it did work but I don't want it to even compile let alone commit and push

Comment: What do you mean with "it did work"? [Here's Babel saying that's not valid syntax.](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=true&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAMTnAFASkQbwFCKIBOAplCEUgDwAmMAbogM5QCeANiQLw46IC2AQyIBzGGAC0UOAAcAXIgDkADhkAPRYgC-WxAD4qAejr09AbjxagA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.17.2&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D)

Comment: Trying to pass that code through Eslint says "Parsing error: Unexpected token `-`".

Comment: I was surprised as you.. it did compile and he sent me a screenshot of the properties appearing in the inspect.

Comment: sorry! forgot to wrote commas around the margin-top. edited

Comment: Do you see https://eslint.org/docs/rules/camelcase ?

Comment: Right. Now that your question includes valid syntax, it looks like you'll need to write your own ESLint rule for this. It sounds like it would be a great addition to [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react) :-)